# save vector as Matlab file

Tags: matlab, save

Does the save function in Matlab save the thing saved in the same project file?
I'm trying to save a vector as 'mat' file. 
This is my code :

```
function    facePts = getFacePts(faceFileName)
    if(exist('faceFileName','file')==2)
        facePts=load('faceFilename.mat'); 
        return;
    end

    img=imread(faceFileName,'tif');
    showImage(img);
    [x,y]=ginput(3);
    facePts=[x,y]';
    facePts=facePts(:);
    save faceFileName.m, facePts;   %%%%% HERE
end
```

The function compiles but I can't find the file I saved

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do this:

```
save('faceFileName.mat', 'facePts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figuered out that the path of the current folder wasn't the path of my Project.
I changed that by going to 'Desktop' in the Bar, checked 'Current Folder' and chaged the path there.
Now it works !